# Cloudformation Lambda with dynamodb streams between two templates

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have two Cloudformation stacks. One of them defines the Dynamodb.

I want the second stack to use the Dynamodb referenced in the first stack. The second stack has a Lambda function which will receive dynamodb stream from stack 1.

How should I export and import dynamodb from one stack to another for Lambda stream consumption?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the DynamoDB table stack, export the [`StreamArn`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-eventsourcemapping.html#cfn-lambda-eventsourcemapping.html) attribute of the table. Use that as the value of the `EventSourceArn` to define an [EventSourceMapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-eventsourcemapping.html#cfn-lambda-eventsourcemapping.html) resource in your Lambda stack.

```
# DynamoDB stack
Resources:
  Table:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      StreamSpecification: NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES  
      # etc.

Outputs:
  TableStreamArn:
    Value: !GetAtt Table.StreamArn
    Export:
      Name: StreamArn

# Lambda stack
Resources:
  Function:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    # etc.

  EventMapping:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping
    Properties:
      EventSourceArn: !ImportValue StreamArn
      FunctionName: !GetAtt Function.Arn
      # etc.
```

You could also do it the other way around - import the Lambda function ARN to the DynamoDB stack and define the event mapping there, but that feels less logical to me.

Answer (score 0):

If your lambda stack looks like this

```
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - stream:
          type: dynamodb
          arn: dynamoStreamArn
```

and you want to consume the dynamoDB stream arn from the stack where dynamoDB is defined, you can use several different options.

**1. Import/Export**

Exporting the dynamo stream arn from the first stack as mentioned in answers before, but import it in lambda stack using [ImportValue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html) function

```
events:
  - stream:
      type: dynamodb
      arn: Fn::ImportValue: NameWhichYouExported
```

**2. Serverless plugins**

Searching for the solution for this problem, found two plugins on NPM that import the stream arn by table name.

[Plugin 1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-dynamo-stream-plugin)

[Plugin 2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-dynamodb-stream-arn-plugin)

Example from one of the plugins:

```
events:
   - stream:
       arn: ${fetchStreamARN(<tableName>)} // This is all the change you need to do
       startingPosition: LATEST
       enabled: true // Any other parameters can be added as provided by serverless
```